# Custom image size in Media Dropdown

Tags: functions, uploads, images

I've tried everything you have said, but it's not working on my site. I'm using the below function:

```
function setup_image_sizes() {
    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
        add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740, 0, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_image_sizes' );*/

function post_image_sizes($sizes){
    $custom_sizes = array(
        'blog_body_img' => 'Blog Body Image'
    );
    return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'post_image_sizes');
```

But in the dropdown it is not coming up. See the screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot]

I would have been posted this on the comment, but unfortunately below 50 reputation, I'm not allowed to comment. So, I'm looking forward for any help.

Also as I'm using a child theme, where I'm overwriting some of my parent theme image type. So, I've also tried this below code, but still not working.

```
function img_update() {
    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
        add_image_size( 'blog_feat_img', 720 ); //overwriting parent theme
        add_image_size( 'latest_posts_widget_feat_img', 400 ); //overwriting parent theme
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_1x', 400 ); //overwriting parent theme
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_2x', 800 ); //overwriting parent theme
        add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740, 0, true ); //My own size
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'img_update', 11 );


    function post_image_sizes($sizes){
        $custom_sizes = array(
            'blog_body_img' => 'Blog Body Image'
        );
        return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );
    }
    add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'post_image_sizes', 11);
```

Please help me to fix this, as I have no idea where I'm doing this wrong. I'm placing this functions in my child theme's function.php. Please help.

**Note:**
I'm already aware that someone else has posted this kind of question before in this forum and I've also checked this thread ([How to get custom image sizes into media uploader dropdown?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105162/how-to-get-custom-image-sizes-into-media-uploader-dropdown)) for reference, but it didn't fixed my issue. Also as I don't have **50** repotation, I cant place comment. So I had no other way to open a new thread for this. I'm sorry.

Comment: can you confirm that these functions are actually getting called by echoing some text?

Comment: Yes they are getting called perfectly.

Comment: I have another question. You see I've mentioned the width of my custom image size as `740` and hight as per the image. Now when I'm regenerating the thumbnails, its generating 650x488 instead it should generate `740x555` as the full image size is `1024x768`. Why this is happening? Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/FPJ6dZm.jpg
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above problem got fixed after regenerating the thumbnails and by using the following function.

```
function mytheme_image_size_names( $sizes ) {
    $sizes['blog_body_img'] = __( 'Blog Body Image', 'isaumya' );

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'mytheme_image_size_names', 11, 1 );
```

Comment: If you have another question, please post it in a new thread. Mixing problems can confuse future users.

Comment: I did. Here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173271/use-exact-image-size-using-add-image-size