# Use Exact Image Size using add_image_size

Tags: functions, images

I have a pretty basic question. It may be very noob question, but it is bothering me a lot. In my theme I've added a custom image size like this:

```
function img_update() {
    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
        add_image_size( 'blog_feat_img', 720 );
        add_image_size( 'latest_posts_widget_feat_img', 400 );
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_1x', 400 );
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_2x', 800 );
        add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740 );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'img_update', 11 );
```

Now I used another function to add that in media dropdown list, like this:

```
function mytheme_image_size_names( $sizes ) {
    $sizes['blog_body_img'] = __( 'Blog Body Image', 'isaumya' );

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'mytheme_image_size_names', 11, 1 );
```

Everything fine but I'm having a wired issue. When Iupload an image of `1024x768` it should generate a `740x555` copy as I didn't mention the height, so it should take the proper height as per that width. But instead it is generating `650x488` version for `blog_body_img`. I have no idea why. I've also tried to pass 0 as height and then `true` as the crop parameter. Still it generates `650x488` version and not `740x555`. Why?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Try `add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740, 600, true );` just for debugging purpose.

Comment: But I don't want to mention the height. I want to be automatically set as per image.

Comment: If you don't want to set a height, why do you expecti that the generated image has a height of 555? How is the aspect ratio set?

Comment: because I want it to the same aspect ratio. Now if the main image size is 1024x768 and if you scale it down to 740 keeping the same aspect ratio, the height automatically will be 555. Try to do it in photoshop. You will see.

Comment: Take a image canvus size of 1024x768 and then try to save for web, give the width 740, the height automatically will be 555

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'm now investigating.

Comment: I've tested `add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740 );`, uploaded an image 1024x768 and I get a image size exactly of 740x555. Strange it is not working for you. Review your code and look for other possible `add_image_size` you may have.

Comment: I've updated the question with all add_image_type I have in my theme. But what other add_image type has to do with this?

Comment: Hey I've found out another interesting thing. When I visit any of my image of `1024x768` like this: https://www.isaumya.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/im-getting-ssl.jpg but putting `-740x555` before the file extension it shows up properly. See this: https://www.isaumya.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/im-getting-ssl-740x555.jpg
But in the dropdown menu this size is not showing up. Any idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19743/discussion-between-isaumya-and-cybmeta).

Comment: I'm sorry but I've made several tests and your code `add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740 );` is working. If the original image width is greater than 740 px, I ge a image of 740 width with auto height, soft cropped. With the information your have provided is not possible to me to find a possible error.

Comment: I'm also saying the same thing. That image is getting generated on my end too. Check my last comment. I can access them via url, but in the drop-down list it is showing that wired site. Also what extra info do you need tell me, I'll provide them here.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Hi, I've fond the issue in my parent there $content_width has set to 650 like this: http://i.imgur.com/GF3ZR0C.jpg but when I tried to overwrite that in my chield theme like this way: http://i.imgur.com/hJcO434.jpg it is not getting overwritten. 
Now can you help me? Overwriting content width will be the solution. Please help.

Comment: I thought we was talking in the chat but it seems I was alone.

Comment: LOL. I'm new here. So learning things up as fast as possible. Sorry for that. Please check my answer. I've figured things out. Please check if I've done it correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I've fixed the issue. In my parent theme, the dev have used the following code

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
{
    $content_width = 650;
}
```

which means if the value of `$content_width` has not set up yet then set it to 650. Now in my chield theme at the time of overwriting and mentioning image type I've just added few more lines like this:

```
function img_update() {
    global $content_width;

    if ( isset( $content_width ) )
    {
        $content_width = 740;
    }

    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
        add_image_size( 'blog_feat_img', 720 );
        add_image_size( 'latest_posts_widget_feat_img', 400 );
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_1x', 400 );
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_2x', 800 );
        add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740 );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'img_update', 11 );
```

This type I have checked if the value of `$content_width` has already been set. Which is virtuosos because my function in priority 11 so the parent theme func with first set the value then I overwrite it.

Every thing is fine now.

**Previous**

[image: wrong image width]

**Now**

[image: everything is ok]

Comment: See the discussion chat I was having http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19743/discussion-between-isaumya-and-cybmeta

Answer (score 0):

Use '9999' as a height limit for the add_image_size function. Thus, you will have your ratio saved without cropping or squishing the image and only width limit will be followed.

<strike>Height is required and has no default value (see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)</strike>

Comment: You are completely wrong. Width and height both are optional in the `add_image_size()` function. Default value is zeo (0). Read the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. The codex says it is optional, the reference says it is required. Only [seeing the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L227) you can be confirmed that is optional with default value set to zero.

Comment: Sorry, guys, but the code reference seemed like a more up-to-date source of info for me. Anyways, I can edit the "no default value" and "required" part, but am absolutely sure about the 9999 value, so do try it out, please.

Comment: OK, I'm trying 9999

Comment: See the source code: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L227 That is the more up-to-date because it is the actual code working in WordPress. And I can confirm from my live tests that height is not required, see my comment on the question.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you (or the source code), mate, I agree with ya :) I'm just explaining why I posted something wrong ;)

Comment: I'm not arguing neither, just explaning why I think you was wrong.

Comment: Guys 9999 trick didnt work. I tried this `add_image_size( 'blog_body_img', 740, 9999 );` and still the same. see the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/nNQD9f4.jpg